# Слова тук и туча — этимологически однокоренные?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Могут ли быть слова *тук* и *туча* этимологически однокоренными?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы это узнать, надо посмотреть в этимологический словарь.

Воспользуемся словарем Черных и увидим, что ***тук*** — это жир, а ***тучнеть*** — значит  ***пухнуть, расти, расширяться***. В общем, направление процесса видится ясным.

**Сложнее с тучей**. Там значение и.-е. корня — **стягиваться, собираться, сгущаться.** Туча нам представляется сгустком облаков, то есть процесс прямо противоположный по направлению.

С другой стороны, это облака сгущаются, а туча-то тоже растет, увеличивается.

Можно сравнить с деньгами. Вы их копите, и они устремляются в ваш кошелек. Это одно направление. В то же время ваше состояние растет, а это другое направление.

Вот и Черных добавляет в статье про тучу: стягиваться, собираться, сгущаться; **расти, преуспевать.**

**Так что вопрос (в заданной форме) остается открытым:** если туча растет, то она "тучнеет" (однокоренные слова), а если сгущается, то это уже не однокоренные слова. В общем, запутаться можно.

Если отвечать на более конкретный вопрос "Слова тук и туча — однокоренные?", то можно сказать следующее: **этимологи эти слова однокоренными не считают.**

**Туча:** о.-с. корень tok, и.-е. корень  tenk. **Тучный**: и.-е. корень teu. В др.-рус. и ст.-сл. языках существовал глагол ***тыти*** — тучнеть.